# Get objects in django queryset from given interval

Tags: python, django, list, django-queryset

I want to get my queryset to return some objects that are in the given interval for example from position 26 until position 30 , my queryset need to have only 3 elements that are on 27 ,28 , 29 positions.My code:

```
object_query_set = Comment.objects.filter(id_chat=id_chat).order_by('-date')[:26-30]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[:26-30]` is just `[:-4]`. You want `[26:30]` (possibly off by one, experiment and adjust).

Comment: Yeah , I'm new in django-python , it's working , thanks , I will accept your answer when I will be able to .